# Importing Multiple css files in to php header

Tags: php, html, css, function

I am just wondering what will be the best way to import multiple css files into php header. Currently four css files are linked to different pages which are being converted into 4 different php header and then being called like require_once **DIR** . '/../templates/header1.inc.php'; is there anyway i can merge them in to one file with function as i am only at beginner level i am definetly getting something wrong here is what i have tried.

```
function aboutAction()
{
  $pageTitle = 'About Us';
}

if ($pageTitle== About Us)
{
  require_once __DIR__ . '/../public/css/style4.css';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear why you want to include a css file into a php file. This will most likely result in a syntax error. css rules are meant for the client side, they have no use on the server side. So refer to them in the html document head section as usual, which also has the advantage that they can be cached by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I ususualy do something like this:

```
<?php if(condition) { ?> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="..
/* or any other html code */
<?php } ?>
```

The CSS will be included only if the condtition is true.